# ThreadedHTTPServer with GUI is not woking in python

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, webserver

I'm writing a simple program in Python. I want the class of `RequestHandler` and class of GUI run in separate thread at the same time and messages that has been generate in RequestHandler, shown in GUI frequently (in every post request will be generate one or two messages). here follows a simplified version of my code:

```
import web
import io,json
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
urls = ('/', 'RequestHandler')

from time import sleep
import threading
from Tkinter import *

serialdata = []
data = True
msguser = ''

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
       length = int(self.headers['Content-length'])
       mylogs=self.rfile.readline(length)
       val= json.loads(mylogs)
       if val['RunningApp'].find('viber') >= 0:          
            msguser = 'viber is running on Devise ID:',val['DeviceID'],'in time:',val['timestamp']
            serialdata.append(msguser)
       if val['RunningApp'].find('telegram.messenger') >= 0:
            msguser = 'Telegram is running on Devise ID:',val['DeviceID'],'in time:',val['timestamp']
            serialdata.append(msguser)

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass

class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.lbl = Label(self.root, text="")
        self.updateGUI()
        self.readSensor()

    def run(self):
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.lbl.after(1000, self.updateGUI)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def updateGUI(self):
        msg = "Data is True" if data else "Data is False"
        self.lbl["text"] = msg
        self.root.update()
        self.lbl.after(1000, self.updateGUI)

    def readSensor(self):
        self.lbl["text"] = serialdata[-1]
        self.root.update()
        self.root.after(527, self.readSensor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('X.X.X.X', 1024), RequestHandler)
    print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
    Gui().run()
    server.serve_forever()
```

When I run it I get error: `self.lbl["text"] = serialdata[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range` 
and also when I gave to `self.lbl["text"]` a static string like "new event is received"

The program not working as multithread and until GUI is running `do_post` never run and work.

Comment: Could you please strip down the code to a Minimal Working Example? There are missing imports (e.g. Tk, ThreadingMixIn), you are using undefined variables (e.g. data and serialdata), etc. You are not helping us help you! To your specific errors, the first one probably means that `serialdata` is empty (i.e. `len(serialdata) == 0`). The second one is probably because `Gui().run()` is a blocking call (it doesn't return), so your code never gets to call `server.serve_forever()`. You should probably look into the [`multiprocessing` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: sorry, there was mistake, I edit my code now, please show me how should I change my code to fix my problem and running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the Server in it's own thread:

```
def main():
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('X.X.X.X', 1024), RequestHandler)
    print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.start()
    Gui().run()
    server.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the beginning `serialdata` is empty, so accessing `serialdata[-1]` fails. So check, if data is available:

```
def readSensor(self):
    if serialdata:
        self.lbl["text"] = serialdata.pop()
    self.root.after(527, self.readSensor)
```

still better, use a queue for communication:

```
import threading
import json
from Queue import Queue, Empty
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import Tkinter as tk

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        length = int(self.headers['Content-length'])
        mylogs = self.rfile.read(length)
        val = json.loads(mylogs)
        if 'viber' in val['RunningApp']:
            app = 'viber'
        if 'telegram.messenger' in val['RunningApp']:
            app = 'Telegram'
        self.server.queue.put('%s is running on Devise ID: %s in time: %s' % (app, val['DeviceID'], val['timestamp']))

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass

class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self, root, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        self.lbl = tk.Label(root, text="")
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.read_sensor()

    def read_sensor(self):
        try:
            self.lbl["text"] = self.queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            pass
        self.lbl.after(527, self.readSensor)

def main():
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('X.X.X.X', 1024), RequestHandler)
    server.queue = Queue()
    print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.start()
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = Gui(root, server.queue)
    root.mainloop()
    server.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: great! thank you very much, your answer is clear and helpful ! one of problems be solved now and multithreading is working but other problem exist yet, the error : `IndexError: list index out of range` I can guess why it occur but i has no idea to fix it

Comment: Tank you very very much Daniel.it work correctly! Just let me notic one thing. putting in gueue cann't be once in code. strings replace on together.it is wrong.